# Mining data across multiple Team Project in TFS 2013 for a particular User

Tags: tfs

Just like the title says, I would like to know if there is any way in TFS 2013 Update 4 to query a whole week-long activity for a certain User (a team member of a certain project) across multiple projects.

An example scenario will be as follows :

User_A is a team-member in Project_1, Project_2, and Project_3.
On Day_1, he performs some work in Project_1 (development : 2 hours, testing 1 hour). He also performs another work in Project_2 (bugfixing : 3 hours). 
On Day_2, he continues his work in Project_2 (bugfixing : 2 hours). And then due to some circumstances, he is required to solve an urgent issue in Project_3 (3 hours). 
And so on until Day_5, shifting back and forth through multiple projects.

Now, our PM would like to know the details of his work during this week (from Day_1 until Day_5).
Is it possible to generate data, perhaps through a query in TFS Web Access to aggregate data for 
User_A in a given timespan ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of questions in here and I will try my best to answer them all:

**Query Across Team Project in Web Access**

First, you can query in Web Access across multiple Projects by just removing the "Team Project" part of the query.

[image]

You can even create charts based on this data...

[image]

However for anything more complicated you should use the built in Reporting Services tool and the Data warehouse that comes with TFS. If you don't have it installed then you can add it.

http://nakedalm.com/integrate-reporting-and-analyses-services-with-team-foundation-server-2013/

This will gave you access to much more powerful reporting but it is much more complicated to configure. You get a cube (multi-dimensional data) and a warehouse (lists) that you can query to your hearts content both across team project and across collections.

**Time Tracking in TFS**

TFS is an effort management system and is not good at time management. While you can get a query to show you the amount of time applied to a Task you can tell when that time was applied without some serious giggery pokery. In TFS (well the MSF templates anyway) you store "Remaining", "Completed", and "Original Estimate".

So today I have a task that I completed 4 hours and tomorrow it will have a value of 8 hours in the completed field.

- So did I complete 8 today? No, I only added 4.
- What if I decided that it was only 3 the day after I entered the data? Can I fix it? No,

I could go on and on with the issues and caveats for trying to track time in TFS, however, if we just assume that it is not possible (or at least more effort than it is worth) then we are left with finding another solution. (Yes, I know there are third party tools that plug onto TFS and do time sheets or other stupid stuff, but they all have issues.)

I recommend tracking course grained time against a Project in a tool is separate from TFS, that is designed to collect this information. I have used Harvest and Freshbooks but there are other time sheeting systems out there. Do not integrate it with TFS. I have never once seen that work effectively and there is no value in it.

**Is there value in tracking time** - Not actually asked but it goes to the crux of the issue

The only demonstrable value I have ever seen in collecting time sheets is a) if you are billing your customers for that time, or b) you need to understand capex vs opex against a project. If both are true then a simple Project in Harvest with two tasks, one for Feature work and one for Maintenance work, will be sufficient and way simpler to manage.